# Display current ranking of post as a number in post title

Tags: post-meta, wpdb, meta-value

I have a page where people can rank stuff. My posts are ordered by the current ranking which is stored as a meta key in post meta.

Now i want to add the current ranking spot within the title of the single post page.

I found this code which is working fine with adding the ranking number according to post date:

```
    class MY_Post_Numbers {

    private $count = 0;
    private $posts = array();

    public function display_count() {
        $this->init(); // prevent unnecessary queries
        $id = get_the_ID();
        echo sprintf( '<div class="post-counter">Post number<span class="num">%s</span><span class="slash">/</span><span class="total">%s</span></div>', $this->posts[$id], $this->count );
    }

    private function init() {
        if ( $this->count )
            return;
        global $wpdb;       
        $posts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date " ); // can add or change order if you want 
        $this->count = count($posts);

        foreach ( $posts as $key => $value ) {
            $this->posts[$value] = $key + 1;
        }
        unset($posts);
    }

}
$GLOBALS['my_post_numbers'] = new MY_Post_Numbers;

function my_post_number() {
    $GLOBALS['my_post_numbers']->display_count();
}
```

Now i only need to make it work with my meta key value instead of order by post_date

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date " );
```

Can someone help me changing this line so i can order by my ranking meta value?

The meta value is a decimal number like e.g. 3.745 .

Kinda lost right now already tried a lot with this but nothing worked yet

Comment: What is your meta key?

Comment: its called  "hp_rating"

Comment: How the rankings are stored in meta?

Comment: the rankings are stored for each custom post called "hp_listing" under the meta_key "hp_rating" and a meta_value from 1-5 but with up to 3 decimals like e.g. 4.755. Everytime a user rates the meta_value gets updated.  I want to number the current ranking DESC and ordered by the meta value so i can use display count from given code to show the current ranking number within the title on the single post page.  Like:   #5 POSTTITLE

Answer (score 0):

Could make it work already :)

```
     class MY_Post_Numbers {

    private $count = 0;
    private $posts = array();

    public function display_count() {
        $this->init(); // prevent unnecessary queries
        $id = get_the_ID();
        echo sprintf( '<div class="post-counter">Post number<span class="num">%s</span><span class="slash">/</span><span class="total">%s</span></div>', $this->posts[$id], $this->count );
    }

    private function init() {
        if ( $this->count )
            return;
        global $wpdb;       
        $posts = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                left join $wpdb->postmeta ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
                WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'hp_listing'
                AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'hp_rating'
                ORDER BY ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_value + 0) DESC");
        $this->count = count($posts);

        foreach ( $posts as $key => $value ) {
            $this->posts[$value] = $key + 1;
        }
        unset($posts);
    }

}
$GLOBALS['my_post_numbers'] = new MY_Post_Numbers;

function my_post_number() {
    $GLOBALS['my_post_numbers']->display_count();
}
```

with

```
<?php my_post_number(); ?>
```

it's possible to use in template file if anyone else is interested